# Pre-compiled Finale substitute for Fedora 20?

Tags: fedora, compiling, rpm, music

I recently lost my dual-booted HDD (with both Linux and Windows). It did some weird stuff and started changing all files to read-only on every start-up. So, I bought a new HDD and put Fedora 20 on it.

Now, the only thing I'm looking to replace is Finale (I have found acceptable substitutes or Linux versions of everything else). I have found MusScore, NoteEdit, etc, but all of these programs need to be compiled (I can't find a suitable .rpm), and typing 'make' gives me errors. First I need `cmake`, then `qmake`, then a whole ton of things I don't recognize, and some of which I don't understand.

Honestly, I've gotten to the point of saying it isn't worth it unless I can find an RPM of something, because compiling things is ridiculously difficult (I don't NEED a music writing program, just want one).

Does anyone know of a suitable replacement already compiled and ready for distribution for Fedora 20?

#### EDIT #1

For those who are unfamiliar with Finale, it is a music-composition software, similar to linux's NoteEdit or MusScore. It allows exportation of audio files, note annotations, and printing pages of musical scores. It also supports transposition and human playback features. Some of these things are not that important to me, and I can do some by hand (like transposition), but I would really like the audio file export and printing features. Here is the about page for Finale:

http://www.finalemusic.com/products/finale/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Method #1 - Using Wine + Finale

If you have Fedora 20 setup and a copy of Finale already you can apparently run it under [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/), at least according to this thread titled:  [Finale 2014 without Windows or Mac](http://forum.makemusic.com/default.aspx?f=5&m=410894).

*excerpt*

> Hey all
>
> Heads up: Finale 2014 is working perfectly on Linux. You can use PlayOnLinux (or basic WINE) and performance is incredible. Of course, if you insist on using VST third-party playback and whatnot, you'll be sad but it's not surprising.
>
> For strictly notation and basic playback, Finale 2014 is golden on Linux. If all you want to do is input and edit scores, then you will be very happy. Finale 2014 on Linux does everything as the other OS can do, minus comprehensive VST support.
>
> Even though Finale is only "supported" on Mac and PC, I figured I would share my findings with the forum in case any other users like myself prefer to use Linux whenever possible.

#### What's Wine?

Wine is an emulation layer that allows Window executables to run under Linux natively. It's not virtualization and it isn't emulation, it's somewhere in between both of these approaches. But it really doesn't matter how it works, just that it does. You can read more of the technology underpinnings on the project's website.

The software application Finale is listed in [Wine's AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=454). It's listed as being Gold or Bronze level for versions 2011 & 2012. This is a pretty good indication that the application should run reasonably well through this approach.

#### Method #2 - MusScore

I did find the package already pre-built for Fedora 20. It's called `mscore` and looks to be in the standard repositories.

- http://pkgs.org/fedora-20/fedora-i386/mscore-1.3-2.fc20.i686.rpm.html

To install it:

```
$ sudo yum install mscore*
```

On Fedora 19 (which I'm currently using) the packages are definitely already available:

```
$ yum search mscore
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, changelog, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
============================================================================================================ N/S matched: mscore ============================================================================================================
mscore-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package mscore
mscore.i686 : Music Composition & Notation Software
mscore.x86_64 : Music Composition & Notation Software
mscore-doc.noarch : MuseScore documentation
mscore-fonts.noarch : MuseScore fonts
```

#### Method #3 - NoteEdit

There is a distro that builds on top of Fedora called CCRMA (pronounced Karma) which is geared towards doing music pre/post production along with video editing.

> Planet CCRMA at Home (CCRMA is pronounced ``karma'') is a collection of free, open source rpm packages (RPM stands for RPM Package Manager) that you can add to a computer running Fedora, 18, 19 or 20, or CentOS 5 (not all applications are built on the 64 bit version) to transform it into an audio workstation with a low-latency kernel, current audio drivers and a nice set of music, midi and audio applications

This distro offers [NoteEdit](http://ccrma.stanford.edu/planetccrma/software/soundapps.html#SECTION000621900000000000000) as a pre-built RPM:

```
$ sudo yum install noteedit
```

You should be able to add the packages from the CCRMA website directly to any stock Fedora 20 system, I'd probably add the CCRMA YUM repositories to the system so that any dependencies can also be automatically downloaded and installed as well.

Details for doing this are covered here:

- http://ccrma.stanford.edu/planetccrma/software/installplanettwenty.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have Finale 2010. Thanks, though, I'll look into running 2010 in Wine or (preferably) PlayonLinux.

Comment: @jaredad7 - I would expect it to work reasonably well. 2010 version is at the Silver level. I've used Wine to use a variety of Window's only applications over the years, it does a reasonably good job at it.

Comment: Wow, I couldn't find ANY rpm's for Fedora 20. Granted, I was looking in to all of this about 2 and 1/2 weeks ago, but I didn't expect it to change that quickly.

Comment: @jaredad7 - I don't think it changed that quickly. Most of the packages are automatically rebuilt from version to version via the project's Koji servers (http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/). This server can be used to by other repos to build their packages too, though many often maintain their own as well. These servers allow for a fairly quick turnaround on rebuilding the various packages for the targeted architectures + releases of Fedora & CentOS as they show up. Finding packages is a bit of an art-form though, I've been using RH distros for 20+ yrs and am pretty adept at it 8-)